# How to get forwaard moving combination of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a following list
lst = [100,200,300,400]

I need the following output [(100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400)]

I did some research and used itertools.combinations library for that

[c for c in itertools.combinations(lst, 2)]

if I use the above code I get the following output which produces all combinations.
[(100, 200), (100, 300), (100, 400), (200, 300), (200, 400), (300, 400)]

I don't want all the combinations, I only want forward moving combinations
how can I get the desired output?

Comment: Checkout `itertools.pairwise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Python 3.10, you can use `itertools.pairwise()`. Otherwise, you can use `zip()`:

```py
lst = [100,200,300,400]
list(zip(lst, lst[1:]))
```

This outputs:

```py
[(100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400)]
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu could achieve this using pure python code.

```py
lst = [100,200,300,400]

new_lst = [(lst[a],lst[a+1]) for a in range(len(lst)) if a<len(lst)-1]
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
[(100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400)]
```

AS @hilberts_drinking_problem comment you can use `itertools.pairwise` also.

```py
from itertools import pairwise
lst = [100,200,300,400]

new_list = list(pairwise(lst))
print(new_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```py
[(100, 200), (200, 300), (300, 400)]
```